# How to instert child entities in JDO (Google App Engine)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

How do i add a record to a child entity in the example below ? For example
i have a Employee Record which is name is "Sam". how do i add 2 street adress for sam ?

Guess i have a

### The Parent entity is Employee

```
import java.util.List;

// ...
@Persistent(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<ContactInfo> contactInfoSets;
```

### The Child key is Adress

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
// ... imports ...

@PersistenceCapable
public class ContactInfo {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String streetAddress;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It just works:

```
Employee sam = new Employee("Sam");
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
addresses.add(new Address("Foo St. 1"));
addresses.add(new Address("Bar Bvd. 3"));
sam.setAddresses(addresses);
persistenceManager.makePersistent(sam);
```

Employee being:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Employee {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    ...
}
```

Address being:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Address {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    ...
}
```

Use `@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")` as the class level annotation. Usually you don't need to annotate any other fields but the key, so the `@Persistent(mappedBy = "employee")` on the `List` is unnecessary.

Btw. I suggest using parametrized collections.

Comment: Hi Hleinone.Thanks for your answer.you suggest to use parametrized collections but what is it ? i'am very new to app engine but i have database knowledge.

Also why @Persistent(mappedBy = "employee") part is unnecessary ?

Comment: Using parametrized collections means that you use List<OfSomeType> instead of just List. About the other question. In a `@PersistenceCapable` class all the fields that are not `static`, `final` or `transient` and are of a persistent type are persisted by default. The `mappedBy` is used for bidirectional relationships and this case propably doesn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting and retrieving Child Entries can be done in the following way:

Parent class Person

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable = "true")
public class Person {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
Long id ;
@Persistent
String strName;
@Persistent
String phnNumber;
@Persistent
String strEmail;
@Nullable
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")
@Element(dependent="true")
//When adding Person Contacts would be added as it is dependent. Also while retrieving
// add defaultFetchGroup = true to retrieve child elements along with parent object.
List<Contacts> lstContacts;

// getter and setter methods
```

}

Dependent Child Class : Contacts

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable = "true")
public class Contacts 
{
@PrimaryKey  
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
Key id;
@Persistent
String email;
@Persistent
String phNumber;
   //getter and setter methods
  }
```